# How to add bash-completion to user www-data?

Tags: linux, bash, debian

when logged in as user 'www-data' on my debian server (squeeze) i want to use bash-completion. I follewed [this guide](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-add-bash-completion-in-debian), but i doesn't succeed:
it is working for all regular users but not for www-data!
what's wrong?

Comment: When you log in as `www-data` often enough that bash completion is worth the hassle, you have a serious problem with the administration.

Comment: Are you sure that www-data has correct shell? Check by `echo $SHELL` or `echo $0` in console.

Comment: @4andrew: that's the fault! 'sh' was the enabled shell ... thanks fpr your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As a normal user with bash completion do:

```
sudo -u www-data #rest of command here#
```

and you'll get the rest of the command allowing bash completion.